# Practical example of WCF being consumed over TCP/IPC/MSMQ

Tags: wcf

I have read about transport schemes supported by WCF several times. It looks very theoretical.Almost everywhere it is described as:

```
Following are the transport schemes supported by WCF:

HTTP/HTTPS - http://localhost:8001/MyService
TCP - net.tcp://localhost:8002/MyService
IPC - net.pipe://localhost/MyPipe
Peer network
MSMQ - net.msmq://localhost/private/MyQueue
Service bus - sb://MyNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/
```

However I could not understand who would require to consume WCF over TCP or IPC or MSMQ. Can anyone give a practical example of who would really need to consume WCF over TCP or any other sceme than HTTP and how would they do so?

Comment: This a very broad question. I recommend buying the book Programming WCF services by Juval Lowy and Michael Montgomery. It goes deep into WCF

Comment: You may have missed this in your research - [Choosing a Transport](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Consuming a WCF-Service over TCP is in my case the most common way if you want two or more Programs to communicate. WCF over tcp can easily replace IPC-Communication.

For example:
You have a Windows-Service hosting an WCF-Service. With Vista and later you have to deal with the Session 0 isolation.
You now want to communiacte with that WCF-Service. A common way to achieve that is a tray-application.
Most Anti-Virus programs do it like this.

If you are operating on the same machine, tcp is way faster than HTTP-Binding.

Comment: If you are operating on the same machine (i.e., client and service are both on the same box) then named pipes (net.pipe://) is going to be your fastest.  TCP can work between different machines.

Answer (score 0):

I have found Tim's comments very useful. I have gone through the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769(v=vs.110).aspx) he had provided and I will try to summarize whatever I have got from it.

> 1. When to use TCP - When host is WCF and consumer is WCF as well use TCP. The communication would be much faster than HTTP.
> 2. When to use Named pipes - When host and consumer both are WCF and reside on same machine. The communication would be faster and the
>      access to the host would be denied from other machines.

You can refer [this](http://prasadhonrao.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/WCF-Binding-Decision-Tree.png) image for more details about choosing appropriate transport. To dig down further refer [this](http://prasadhonrao.com/wcf-binding-decision-tree/).